# GFCI to Outlet controlled by Switch

Tags: electrical, receptacle, gfci

I have an existing GFCI outlet under my sink dedicated to my dishwasher.  I want to add an outlet next to the GFCI that can be controlled by a switch for my garbage disposal.  There is 14/2 wire running into the receptacle with the GFCI.  I pulled some 14/3 from the switch to the same receptacle to control the new outlet.  I attached a picture to give an idea of what I'm talking about.  The power coming in will connect to the line side of the GFCI. The run the neutral and hot out of the load side to the outlet.  I'm not sure how to incorporate the switch.  I would appreciate any guidance.

Thank you!
[image]

Comment: Why use a receptacle at all? Why not hard-wire the disposal? Then you have load hot go to black up to switch, load neutral white split to go to switch (where it will be capped unused, but newer code requires it to be present) and the disposal, switched hot red from switch to disposal and ground everywhere (of course). If the existing GFCI box has enough space then you don't even need a new box (which otherwise you will need to mount the new receptacle).

Comment: FWIW I put an outlet and a plug on my garbage disposal for those gross but necessary times I had to stick my hand in the disposal to get something out that shouldn't have been in it. 'Twas a good feeling of safety knowing I had the disposal plug in one hand while the other was going in for the dive, and it couldn't turn on because it was unplugged, and no one could flip a switch or a breaker and buzz my hand.

Comment: @Triplefault Totally understood. But a bonus of the GFCI protection (required now, not when I redid my kitchen 20+ years ago) is that if the GFCI is nearby (as this one is), you can: Push the TEST button the GFCI; verify with the switch that the disposal is indeed truly unpowered (and then turn the switch off anyway) and the only way the disposal could then turn on is if somebody *both* pressed the GFCI reset *and* turned on the switch.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact, do these work differently in US? Down under they flip the RCDs (their name here) on that circuit at the board as well, because i think they just short the ground to neutral.  Also, it is a requirement to have an override switch above the bench.

Comment: Just liked the idea of having the other outlet controlled by the switch.  The disposal already has a cord attached so I figured just wiring the outlet to work off the switch would be the easiest solution.

Comment: @Rohit Australia uses the European model of using an RCD that protects several circuits at once, but that requires a more mild detection threshold (or you'd have constant nuisance trips from so many things protected). In America our GFCIs go on circuits or parts of circuits and the sensitivity is cranked up to 5mA.  But yes, the gold standard for the "test" button is to bridge Load live to Line neutral through a resistor.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica wouldn't the test be live load to ground through a resistor?

Comment: @Jim ground might not be there.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I can see I am missing something. I thought the GFCI circuitry compared the current in the hot conductor to the current in the neutral and if they were the same (within the sensitivity) then the breaker stayed closed, i.e., passing current. How could passing current through a resistor from hot to neutral cause an error condition? OK I get it now. The test circuitry has the current in either the hot or the neutral (but not both) bypass the testing point so there is an imbalance at the testing point.

Comment: @Jim yes, the resistor crosses from line to load side, creating an imbalance.

Comment: If the end wires of this size of resistor were to be inserted into the hot and neutral slots in the receptacle, then it would not trip the GFCI, right? – 
Jim Stewart

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest solution, a cable goes from the GFCI to the switch box, and another from the switch box to the outlet. At the switch box, white goes to white, ground to ground, and one black goes to each of the switch terminals.

If this is impractical, the wiring can go from GFCI to outlet box, and a second cable goes from outlet box  to the switch. This is a bit more complicated and I'm not up for describing it again right now; search past answers for "switch loop".